# Python3 print statement doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Python 3.2.2

```
>>> s = 'hhh'
>>> print s
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> print(s)
hhh
>>> print 2*2
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> print(2*2)
4
```

Why do I have to use `print("...")` to print something?  If I dno't it complains with 'SyntaxError'.

Comment: This damage to backwards compatibility was done on purpose and is most of the reason why it's going to take another 15 years or so for everyone to get around to python3.  Python3 is just not compatible.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As of python 3.0, `print` is a function. See:

http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function